# Pass a user-defined table as a select statement to a Stored Procedure or Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question applies to Stored Procedures and Functions.

Let's say we have a User-Defined Table named *udt_Points* which has two columns: X and Y, which are both floats. Furthermore, let's say we have a function *udf_RollingAverage* which takes the *udf_Points* User-Defined Table as an argument and returns a table of X and its corresponding Rolling Average.

As of now, the current method of implementation would be as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @points AS udt_Points;
INSERT INTO @point VALUES
(0,1),
(1,2)

SELECT X, RollingAverage FROM udf_RollingAverage(@points)
```

However, I'm wondering if it is possible to pass the same information as a select statement:

```sql
DECLARE @points AS udt_Points;
INSERT INTO @point VALUES
(0,1),
(1,2)

-- Results in an error
SELECT X, RollingAverage FROM udf_RollingAverage((SELECT X,Y FROM @points))
```

The above case is trivial. However, my issue is that I have a table with has an X column and multiple Y values I would like to pass to such a function. Here is an example of what I would like to happen.

```sql
DECLARE @tmp AS TABLE (
    X FLOAT,
    Y1 FLOAT,
    Y2 FLOAT
)
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES
(0,1,2),
(1,2,3)

SELECT X, T1.RollingAverage, T2.RollingAverage FROM @tmp T
INNER JOIN udf_RollingAverage((SELECT X, Y1 FROM @tmp)) AS T1
    ON T.X = T1.X
INNER JOIN udf_RollingAverage((SELECT X, Y2 FROM @tmp)) AS T2
    ON T.X = T2.X
```

Perhaps this is wishful thinking, but is there any such way to make this work?

EDIT: Attempted the following without any luck. It throws the following error: `Invalid column name 'CTE_T1'`

```sql
DECLARE @tmp AS TABLE (
    X FLOAT,
    Y1 FLOAT,
    Y2 FLOAT
)
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES
(0,1,2),
(1,2,3)

WITH CTE_T1 AS (
    SELECT X,Y FROM @tmp
)
SELECT * FROM udf_RollingAverage(CTE_T1)
```

Comment: have you tried using `recursive CTE`

Comment: I gave it a shot - However, it doesn't appear to be working as expected.

Comment: You can loop through udt_Points values via cursor and pass them into the select/function

Comment: @Nickolay: That is the answer to my problem, thank you!

Comment: @alexherm: I can't pass in individual points but the whole table, as Rolling Average is dependent on the entire table for its calculation as the calculation depends on aggregate functions.